# Having localhost error while using gitian-builder, Compiling gitian-win32.yml for altcoin

Tags: c++, compilation, kvm, cryptocurrency

```
./bin/gbuild ../geranium/contrib/gitian-descriptors/boost-win32.yml
--- Building for precise amd64 ---
Stopping target if it is up

Making a new image copy
Formatting 'target-precise-amd64.qcow2', fmt=qcow2 size=12884901888 backing_file=base-precise-amd64.qcow2 encryption=off cluster_size=65536 lazy_refcounts=off refcount_bits=16
Starting target
Checking if target is up..............................
ssh: connect to host localhost port 2223: Cannot assign requested address
./bin/gbuild:23:in `system!': failed to run on-target true (RuntimeError)
        from ./bin/gbuild:76:in `build_one_configuration'
        from ./bin/gbuild:341:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
        from ./bin/gbuild:336:in `each'
        from ./bin/gbuild:336:in `block in <main>'
        from ./bin/gbuild:334:in `each'
        from ./bin/gbuild:334:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.